# Pytorch Tensorboard Add_graph "Cannot insert a Tensor that requires grad as a constant"

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, tensorboard

I am trying to use torch.utils.tensorboard to log my neural network's structure. But, I am having the following error when I use the add_graph function of the writer:

```
Cannot insert a Tensor that requires grad as a constant. Consider making a parameter or input, or detaching the gradient.
```

Then it prints a Tensor of shape (512, 512), which is equal to one of the hidden layers of the model's input and output dimensions.

The code I was using is as follows:

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
writer = SummaryWriter()
input_tensor = torch.Tensor(...., require_grads=False)
writer.add_graph(model, input_tensor)
```

I Googled around but only found several posts with the same error message but completely different causes.

The versions of the libraries are:

```
Python 3.8.12
pytorch                   1.10.1     py3.8_cuda11.3_cudnn8.2.0_0    pytorch
cudatoolkit               11.3.1
tensorboard                   2.7.0
CUDA Version: 11.2
```

Comment: Can you add `writer.add_graph(model, input_tensor.detach())`? [Motivation](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.1/generated/torch.Tensor.detach.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer this without seeing your model. What I believe is happening is that your model has hanging layers with (for example) convolutional tensors in them that have not been passed to the gpu, and so are not parameters.

Try running:

```
model.cuda()
model.parameters()
```

to see if you get the model you expect.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32608840)

Answer (score 0):

I my case, I got the error message when tracing a model which was ill-formed in pytorch terms.
Specifically, `nn.Module` needs to register all layers and submodules internally. If a layer / module is not registered but encountered during the trace, the cryptic error message is raised.

In most cases, registering is done during `__init__` by either:

- assigning submodules as instance attributes (`nn.Module` catches these by overriding `__setattr__`): `self.module = ...`
- explicit via `self.add_module(...)` or `self.register_module(...)`

The causes for a failed registration can be diverse and subtle when using nested submodules or fancy logic in `__init__`. The printed tensor may be helpful to find the missing module.
In any case, it should be a safe bet to check if all direct submodules appear in `self._modules`.

The same thing applies to Parameters (`self._parameters`) and Buffers (`self._buffers`). The [source code of `nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html) might be worth looking at when in doubt.

In my case, I used a dataclass to bundle multiple submodules, and just assigning the dataclass caused `nn.Module` to miss the actual submodules inside.

There are probably other causes for this error message, because the message text seems not descriptive of the problem, but something different. Anyways, I wanted to share my solution because I did not find it mentioned online already.